# Dims being used by .class File

Tags: class, vb.net

I have this and I want to use something similar to the way Java uses .class files to be able to call events and use them in my main code.

The problem is that I cannot get the .class file to use my Dims

Form1.vb:

```
Namespace LFS_External_Client
    Public Class Form1
        Inherits Form

        Private OutGauge As OutGaugeInterface

        Dim SpeedPref As String
        Dim FuelCapacity As String
        Dim Fuel As String

        Public Sub New()
            InitializeComponent()
        End Sub

        Private Sub Form1_Load() Handles MyBase.Load
            Some Code
            GetFuel()
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Then in the Dataproccer.vb (.class file):

```
Public Class DataProcesser
    Public Sub GetFuel()
        Some Code
        Fuel = og.Fuel.ToString() * FuelCapacity
    End Sub
End Class
```

Code was shortened but has all of the relevant and necessary parts.

Comment: Looks to me like the scope of your variable is limited to the class it was declared in.

Comment: you might want to pass FuelCapacity though your getfuel method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the actual variables from the form instead of passing them through the method calls, you would need to declare them public instead of using dim:

```
...
Private OutGauge As OutGaugeInterface

Public SpeedPref As String
Public FuelCapacity As String
Public Fuel As String
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim FuelCapacity As String

Private Sub Form1_Load() Handles MyBase.Load
            Some Code
            DataProcesser.GetFuel(FuelCapacity)
End Sub

Public Shared Sub GetFuel(Byval FuelCapacity as string)
        Some Code
        Fuel = og.Fuel.ToString() * FuelCapacity
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the MSDN page for the [Dim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee5a7s1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) Statement.

It states:

> Code outside a class, structure, or module must qualify a member
>   variable's name with the name of that class, structure, or module.
>   Code outside a procedure or block cannot refer to any local variables
>   within that procedure or block.

Also according to this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235296.aspx) the default access level for the Dim Statement is Private at the Module Level.

So why not make GetFuel a function and pass the FuelCapacity in like @kcBeard states and return the Fuel value.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load() Handles MyBase.Load    
    Some Code    
    Fuel = DataProcesser.GetFuel(FuelCapacity)    
End Sub    

Public Shared Function GetFuel(Byval FuelCapacity as string) as string
    Some Code
    return og.Fuel.ToString() * FuelCapacity
End Function
```

Comment: Absolutely if your going to return a calculation on fuel throughout multiple classes make it a shared function.

Comment: And if fuel needs more methods just make a class to handle everything that will happen with Fuel.

Answer (score 0):

You can make SpeedPref, FuelCapacity and Fuel public member variables, however a better approach would be to make them properties on the class with appropriate getters and setters. Dim just declares a variable. Please see the modified code sample below:

```
Form1.vb:
Namespace LFS_External_Client
Public Class Form1
    Inherits Form

    Private OutGauge As OutGaugeInterface

    Private _SpeedPref As String
    Private _FuelCapacity As String
    Private _Fuel As String

    Public Property SpeedPref
        Get
            return _SpeedPref
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _SpeedPref = value 
        End Set
    End Property

    ...

End Class
End Namespace
```